# Send two keys with post in my value=""

Tags: php

I wonder how i could send two primary keys with my POST? So far i can only figure out how i can send one. This is how i get one with my button `value='$id'` And now i need my $key also so i can update my sql.
Do i need to do it in a array? or make a string with them two together?

My db

```
    while((db2_fetch_row($queryexe)) and ($counter < $max)) {
     $key = db2_result($queryexe, 'PKEY');
     $id = db2_result($queryexe, 'PID');
     $akt = db2_result($queryexe, 'AKT');
```

Tables + my button

```
print("<td>$key</td>\n");
print("<td class='center'>$id</td>\n");
print("<td><form class='form-horizontal' method='post'><button  name = 'test' 
type='submit' id = 'test' value='$id' class='btn btn-default'>
<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-repeat'></i> Klar
  </button></form></td>\n");
```

And my button

```
       if(isset($_POST['test'])) {
                $dbhost = '***';
                $dbuser = '***';
                $dbpass = '***';

                $conn = db2_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

                if(! $conn ) {
                   die('Could not connect: ');
                }


                $sql = "UPDATE MYDB SET AKT = 'X' 
                WHERE PKEY = '$key' AND PID = $id ";
                $retval =  db2_exec( $conn, $sql);

                if(! $retval ) {
                  die('Could not update data: ' . db2_stmt_errormsg());
                }
                echo "Updated data successfully\n";
                db2_close($conn); 
             }   


}
```

Comment: You could use Input type hidden: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_hidden

Comment: Add a separate field for your key, e.g. `<input type="hidden" name="key" value="XY">`

Comment: You have pasted in a piece of code in an edit `<input type='hidden' name='key' value='$key' >` and `$_POST['key'];` taken from an answer below without marking it as an additional edit. You shouldn't do that, since that person may get downvoted for it. I have rolled it back to its original state.

Comment: `<input type='hidden' name='key' value='$key'>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres an input type called `hidden` it's basically a way to pass a variable but never actually show it. like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="key" value="$key" >
```

After submitting, `$_POST['key']` = the value of this hidden field.

Comment: ok thank you. should i do this inside my post 'test' ?  if(isset($_POST['key'])) {

Comment: @Moe The hidden field should be in your form, the `$_POST['key']` should be in the `if(isset($_POST["test"])){` yes

Comment: Could you check my edit? Did i put post key in wrong? Atm its updating all my tables.

Comment: @Moe You have: `$_POST['key'];` instead of `$key=$_POST['key'];`

Comment: Thank you for helping me. But we are soon on finish line. Now when i did like u said. It updates all on the same key..It should just update on that specific key and specific id

Comment: @Moe make sure $key from the database is only 1 value. If its an array of data, you need to loop through it. Same with the $id variablr.